# Keypad Slide Up when button was pressed

Tags: android, animation, button

I would like to add a button such that when it was first time being pressed, the keypad will slide down, and then when it was pressed again, the keypad will slide up. Coded as follows:

### Code:

```
    btn_hide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()    
    {
        public void onClick(View view) 
        {
            press ++;
            Utilities.custom_toast(Check_Result.this, "press=", ""+press, "long");
            if (press %2 ==1)
            {
                move(keyboard_frame, 0, 0, 0, (Y_end-Y_begin)); 
            }
            else
            {
                move(keyboard_frame, 0, 0, (Y_end-Y_begin), 0); 
            }
        }
    });

private void move(View view, float X0, float X1, float Y0, float Y1)
{
    view.clearAnimation();
    TranslateAnimation translate =  new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, X0,          // from X0
                                                            Animation.ABSOLUTE, X1,         // to X1
                                                            Animation.ABSOLUTE, Y0,         // from Y0
                                                            Animation.ABSOLUTE, Y1);        // to Y1
    translate.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    translate.setDuration(800);
    translate.setFillAfter(true);
    view.startAnimation(translate);
}
```

### Question:

The keypad is showing by default. When the `btn_hide` is pressed, the keypad can be slide down properly and stayed at destination point.

However, the `btn_hide` seem is disabled and unable to be pressed again (no custom toast is shown), and therefore the keypad cannot be slided up.

I would like to ask why the `btn_hide` is disabled, and how could the above code be modified to make it work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: thanks for your comment. Yet anyway, when pressing it for several times, at least it will slide up and down. Yet now it does not do so. I have tried to change `setFillAfter` to be false, the button is then not being disabled, but the keypad will pop back to its original position after the animation ends. How could the ending position of keypad being kept and at the same time the button is not being disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TranslateAnimation`  in API below `HoneyComb` doesn't actually move the button but only it's image. It's click will be on same place. If you are supporting API 11 and above, use [ObjectAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) instead. Else, register a listener on the animation object and in `onAnimationEnd()`, move the button to its new location.

Comment: thanks, I at last has implemented `AnimationListener` for making the keypad visible / invisible upon finish of the animation.